# List attributes on an Allen-Bradley sensor gateway

Tags: sensors, plc

I'm want to read sensor data from an A-B 1734-AENTR device using [EtherNet/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherNet/IP). As a proof of concept, I'm trying to use [cpppo](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo) to read values. The object addresses are in the form of `@1/1/1`, so I'm getting data with commands like:

```
python -m cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute -a 192.168.1.2 --print '@1/1/1'
```

- Can I view sensor data like this?
- How can I find out the CIP object addresses of the sensors?
- Do I need to specify a route?
- Is there a better utility for doing this?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? I'm using the package and I'm able to get data from a tag so maybe I can help

Comment: Thanks @BitcoinMurderousManiac, but I ended up using different hardware.